# asp.net C# :cannot convert from 'string' to '<anonymous type error>'

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

i'm trying to implement SQL query  using  entity framework

```
select IDVC,CHECKNO,SUBSTRING(ltrim(rtrim(convert(nvarchar,CHECKDATE))),1,4) + '-' + 
                    SUBSTRING(ltrim(rtrim(convert(nvarchar,CHECKDATE))),5,2) + '-' + 
                    SUBSTRING(ltrim(rtrim(convert(nvarchar,CHECKDATE))),7,2) as 
                    CHECKDATE,AMTRMITHC from imdad.dbo.CWHDR  where  IDVC   in 
                    (select IDCUST from  Imdad.dbo.ARCUSO where VALUE like '%10264%'
                    and OPTFIELD='ACCPACCUST')  and transstts='2'
                    Order by CHECKDATE
```

what i do is:

```
var idcust = (from arc in db2.ARCUSOes
              where arc.VALUE.Contains("10264") && arc.OPTFIELD == "ACCPACCUST"
              select new
              {
                  arc.IDCUST

              }).ToList();
```

this is the inner sql statement which will return a list of items like in this screenshot:

[image]

then i tried to implement the in clause:

```
   var data = (from ch in db2.CWHDRs
                where
                idcust.Contains(ch.IDVC) && ch.TRANSSTTS = "2"
                select new
                {
                   idvc=ch.idvc

                });
```

to select the rest of columns but I stopped by an error :

> cannot convert from 'string' to 'anonymous type error'

the syntax error under `ch.IDVC` that located in contains statement

can any one figure out what the wrong?

> Update code:

this is the ARCUSO

```
public partial class ARCUSO
{
    public string IDCUST { get; set; }
    public string OPTFIELD { get; set; }
    public decimal AUDTDATE { get; set; }
    public decimal AUDTTIME { get; set; }
    public string AUDTUSER { get; set; }
    public string AUDTORG { get; set; }
    public string VALUE { get; set; }
    public short TYPE { get; set; }
    public short LENGTH { get; set; }
    public short DECIMALS { get; set; }
    public short ALLOWNULL { get; set; }
    public short VALIDATE { get; set; }
    public short SWSET { get; set; }
}
```

this CWHDR class

```
public partial class CWHDR
{
    public string BTCHTYPE { get; set; }
    public decimal CNTBTCH { get; set; }
    public decimal CNTENTR { get; set; }
    public decimal AUDTDATE { get; set; }
    public decimal AUDTTIME { get; set; }
    public string AUDTUSER { get; set; }
    public string AUDTORG { get; set; }
    public string IDBANK { get; set; }
    public string CURNCODE { get; set; }
    public decimal DATERATE { get; set; }
    public string RATETYPE { get; set; }
    public decimal RATEEXCHHC { get; set; }
    public short RATEOP { get; set; }
    public string TRANSNO { get; set; }
    public decimal TRANSDATE { get; set; }
    public short RMITTYPE { get; set; }
    public string FISCYR { get; set; }
    public string FISCPER { get; set; }
    public short ONHOLD { get; set; }
    public short TRANSSTTS { get; set; }
    public string CHECKNO { get; set; }
    public decimal CHECKDATE { get; set; }
    public string IDVC { get; set; }
    public string NAMEVC { get; set; }
    public decimal AMTPR { get; set; }
    public decimal AMTBC { get; set; }
    public decimal AMTVCTC { get; set; }
    public decimal AMTRMITHC { get; set; }
    public decimal CNTAPPLIED { get; set; }
    public decimal AMTDISCTC { get; set; }
    public decimal AMTDISCHC { get; set; }
    public string MANUAL { get; set; }
    public string BANKDRAW { get; set; }
    public string CURNVC { get; set; }
    public string RATETYPETC { get; set; }
    public decimal DATERATETC { get; set; }
    public decimal RATEEXCHTC { get; set; }
    public short RATEOPTC { get; set; }
    public string TEXTNAME { get; set; }
    public string TEXTSTRE1 { get; set; }
    public string TEXTSTRE2 { get; set; }
    public string TEXTSTRE3 { get; set; }
    public string TEXTSTRE4 { get; set; }
    public string NAMECITY { get; set; }
    public string CODESTTE { get; set; }
    public string CODEPSTL { get; set; }
    public string CODECTRY { get; set; }
    public string NAMECTAC { get; set; }
    public string TEXTPHON1 { get; set; }
    public string TEXTPHON2 { get; set; }
    public short DOCTYPE { get; set; }
    public string DOCNBR { get; set; }
    public decimal CNTLSTLINE { get; set; }
    public short SWPRINTED { get; set; }
    public string CHECKLANG { get; set; }
    public short GLPOST { get; set; }
    public string GLACC1 { get; set; }
    public string GLACC2 { get; set; }
    public string NEWBANK { get; set; }
    public short NEWSTAT { get; set; }
    public string CCMCTYPE { get; set; }
    public decimal RLZDATE { get; set; }
    public string COMMENTS { get; set; }
    public decimal EFDATE { get; set; }
    public decimal AMTPPAYTC { get; set; }
    public string ENTRYDESC { get; set; }
    public string CCMCGUID { get; set; }
    public decimal AASCNTBTCH { get; set; }
    public decimal AASCNTENTR { get; set; }
    public short ORIGPDC { get; set; }
    public string CLEARACCT { get; set; }
    public string REFERENCE { get; set; }
    public short RECSTATUS { get; set; }
    public short SWPRNTRMIT { get; set; }
    public decimal REMUNAPL { get; set; }
    public short SWNEEDPR { get; set; }
    public decimal REMUNAPLTC { get; set; }
    public short LANGUAGE { get; set; }
    public decimal DEPSPNUM { get; set; }
    public decimal AMTDISCBC { get; set; }
    public int VALUES { get; set; }
    public short PROCESSCMD { get; set; }
    public string SOURCECODE { get; set; }
    public decimal APPLIEDAMT { get; set; }
    public string CHKFISCYR { get; set; }
    public string CHKFISCPER { get; set; }
    public short SWJOB { get; set; }
    public short APPLYMETH { get; set; }
    public short SWJOBUPGR { get; set; }
    public string PAYMCODE { get; set; }
    public short PAYMTYPE { get; set; }
    public decimal CNTMC { get; set; }
    public decimal AMTMCHC { get; set; }
    public decimal AMTMCBC { get; set; }
    public decimal AMTMCTC { get; set; }
    public string DISTRSET { get; set; }
    public decimal AMTTOTHC { get; set; }
    public decimal AMTTOTBC { get; set; }
    public decimal AMTTOTTC { get; set; }
    public decimal GLMCBATCH { get; set; }
    public decimal GLMCENTRY { get; set; }
    public short SEQNUM { get; set; }
    public string EFYR { get; set; }
    public string EFPER { get; set; }
    public string IDACCTSET { get; set; }
    public decimal DATEACTVPP { get; set; }
    public short SWPRVOUCH { get; set; }
    public decimal DEPDATE { get; set; }
    public string PTNO { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Try `ch.TRANSSTTS == "2"` not  `ch.TRANSSTTS = "2"`

Comment: Happens to me all the time when I am writing linq. My mind constantly tries to write TSql syntax in the linq and linq syntax in the TSql. Especially with `=`  vs `==` and single quote/double quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use:

```
ch.TRANSSTTS == "2"
```

instead

```
 ch.TRANSSTTS = "2"
```

**Edit**

`idcust` must be `List<string>` try use this code it working

```
public void Test()
    {
        List<ARCUSO> arcuso = new List<ARCUSO>();
        arcuso.Add(new ARCUSO() {IDCUST = "10264", OPTFIELD = "ACCPACCUST", VALUE = "hj10264"});
        arcuso.Add(new ARCUSO() {IDCUST = "F1.10264", OPTFIELD = "ACCPACCUST", VALUE = "gg10264"});
        arcuso.Add(new ARCUSO() {IDCUST = "F2.10264", OPTFIELD = "ACCPACCUST", VALUE = "gg10264"});
        arcuso.Add(new ARCUSO() {IDCUST = "F4.10264", OPTFIELD = "ACCPACCUST", VALUE = "tt10264"});
        arcuso.Add(new ARCUSO() {IDCUST = "F3.4510264", OPTFIELD = "test", VALUE = "tt10264"});


        List<CWHDR> cwhdrs = new List<CWHDR>();
        cwhdrs.Add(new CWHDR() {TRANSSTTS = 2, IDVC = "10264"});
        cwhdrs.Add(new CWHDR() {TRANSSTTS = 2, IDVC = "F1.10264"});
        cwhdrs.Add(new CWHDR() {TRANSSTTS = 2, IDVC = "F2.10264"});
        cwhdrs.Add(new CWHDR() {TRANSSTTS = 2, IDVC = "F4.10264"});
        cwhdrs.Add(new CWHDR() {TRANSSTTS = 5, IDVC = "F3.4510264"});

        List<string> idcust = (from arc in arcuso
            where arc.VALUE.Contains("10264") && (arc.OPTFIELD == "ACCPACCUST")
            select arc.IDCUST).ToList();

        var data = (from ch in cwhdrs
            where idcust.Contains(ch.IDVC) && (ch.TRANSSTTS == 2)
            select new
            {
                idvc = ch.IDVC
            }).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: another error appears when i implement ==  
 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'short' and 'string'

Comment: @faresAyyad so use `ch.TRANSSTTS == 2`

Comment: i use like this: ch.TRANSSTTS == '2' and everything is OK

Comment: every thing is ok in ch.TRANSSTTS == 2 but what about the error in the subject of the topic

Comment: @faresAyyad Be sure `idcust` is type of `List<string>` also update question and add models  `ARCUSOes` and `CWHDRs`

Comment: I update the question but really don't know how to create  `var idcust` to list is it like this `var ids = new List<string> { idcust.ToString() };` ?

Comment: @faresAyyad Look at my update. Apply this change this resolve your problem

Comment: OMG that was very helpful thank you, Yes of course `IDCUST`   is  string in model arcuso `public string IDCUST { get; set; }` thankssss

Answer (score 0):

let this be the data from the database

```
  IList<TempClass> table = new List<TempClass>()
                                    {
                                        new TempClass() { IDVC = "1024",TRANSSTTS = "1"},
                                        new TempClass() { IDVC = "F5.1024",TRANSSTTS = "2"},
                                        new TempClass() { IDVC = "F2.1024",TRANSSTTS = "3"},
                                        new TempClass() { IDVC = "F7.1024",TRANSSTTS = "4"},
                                        new TempClass() { IDVC = "F3.1024",TRANSSTTS = "5"}

        };
```

and this your ids

```
List<string> custIds = new List<string>() { "1024", "F1.1024", "F2.1024", "F3.1024" };
```

and this linq returns "**F2.1024**"

```
var data = from t in table
               where 
               custIds.Contains(t.IDVC) 
               && t.TRANSSTTS == "3"
               select new
                          {
                              t.IDVC
                          };
```

Comment: first of all thanks for your answer but i tried to get the information for idcust 
as a list and it appears as i expect when i trace it in debug mode my problem is when i implement the IN clause  the error appears under ch.IDVC